# How add custom field with product image upload in Virtuemart?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am using Virtuemart 2.0.2 with Joomla 1.7.

I want to customize virtuemart to show particular product images by selecting their color.

but I cant find the file/code in virtuemart from where I can add value of custom field "product color" also while saving the product images to database.

I want to add value of custom field "product color" when saving the product images so that I can identify which product image is related to which color.

I have done this in earlier versions of virtuemart but cant figure out it in virtuemart 2.0.2.

Have been stuck on this from very long time.
Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Upload your color-images to the Media Files trough the VM Backend. (such as red.jpg, blue.jpg, etc.)
2. Create new custom field:

   - Type: Image
   - Title: Color
   - Cart Attribute: Yes (so it will be effective in the cart)
   - Leave the rest untouched
3. At the single product settings go to the Custom field tab
4. Add new "Color" custom field, and choose the proper filename (red.jpg)
5. Add new "color" again, and again ... (blue.jpg ... etc)
6. *(You can use prices to increase/decrease the product-price depends on the color, or you can leave it constant).*
7. Save
8. If You don't add price, you will see: "No additional charge". You can remove or change this text in the language ini some. (ROOT/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_virtuemart.ini - of course in other language you should find the proper ini, such as ROOT/language/hu-HU/hu-HU.com_virtuemart.hu)

   - COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_PRICE_FREE="modified text" or COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_PRICE_FREE=""

(Note: You might need to create some CSS for this function on your frontend)